# What is the proper way of inserting an html file template in a php email

Tags: php

What is the proper way of inserting an html file template in a php email

```
ob_start();
include("example.html");
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

or

```
   file_get_contents();
```

im not sure how to use this

Comment: Maybe you can try both and see which one works best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly depends on what example.html is doing. If it is just plain html both ways work the same.

With include you have variables you define earlier available in example.html.